# jQuery UI multiselect rendering components far away from actual control

Tags: jquery-ui, multi-select

I am using the jquery.multiselect library, which works perfectly in chrome.

I am using css styles which can be viewed [here](https://github.com/linkedin/white-elephant/blob/master/server/vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery.multiselect.less)

Usage:

```
$("#component").multiselect(
            { 
                multiple: true,
                height: '30px', 
                selectedText: "# selected",
                noneSelectedText: "Select Items", 
                checkAllText: "All",
                uncheckAllText: "None"              
            });
```

This works **perfectly** in chrome, but when I attempt to view in firefox or IE, upon opening the select, it renders way down to the bottom left of the screen and it seems like the z-index isn't working at all.  I've researched this a bit and it sounds like there may be a bug with jQuery 1.8.1 (which I am using) however, the [hotfix](https://github.com/aetchegoyen/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/commit/c4b60b2d530804d7a51625f2b850a902b51d5d55)
 didn't seem to work.

Any ideas as to why this would work in chrome, but not in other browsers?

The issue reported [here](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/issues/302) seems very similar, as well.

It also may be valid to note that I am placing the combobox inside an accordion, but since it works in chrome, I am confident that this shouldn't be an issue.  I'm concerned that position:absolute (in some of the styles) may be causing issues in some browsers, but it may be a red herring.

I'm lost on this one, please help!  Thanks.

Comment: It is probably simple to fix (maybe a few lines of CSS) and it's much more likely a bug in your implementation rather than jqueryui bug. You have to post the markup and all your css on jsfiddle, or have a publicly-viewable page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick you can try is to use firebug or chrome inspector to figure out the offending element -- the outermost element that's not where it's supposed to be. Try adding "position: relative" to the parent of this element. That will probably get it at least closer to where you need it to be. If that doesn't work, try adding "position: relative" to the parent's parent and so on until the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery 1.8+, it could be caused by the new implementation of `outerHeight(false)`.

In the jquery-ui-multiselect-widget version 1.13 source line 573: 
top: pos.top + button.outerHeight(),

changing this to:

```
top: pos.top + button.outerHeight(false),
```

fixed my problem.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, buy in my version of multiselect a `position: absolute` was missing in the styles for the dropdown and was causing the problem in some scenarios.

Adding it to `.ui-multiselect-menu` class solved the problem.